# Open model box gets last value from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have received my callback and have appended the data into a div, however I am trying to open a model box that shows google maps and images but the value that I am trying to pass keeps selecting the last record in my hotel list rather that the one that I have selected from the list.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&city=Sydney&stateProvinceCode=QL&countryCode=AU&&numberOfResults=10&_type=json",
    results:{'pageSize':25},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;

        $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {

            var StrlowRate = parseInt(value.lowRate);

            $('.span9').append('<div class="listings"><div class="row"><div class="span2"><a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"><img src="http://images.travelnow.com' + value.thumbNailUrl + '" height="110" width="110"' + 'alt="' + value.name + '"/></a></div><div class="span5" style="margin-left:-20px;"><h4 class="media-heading"><a href="' +'../steven_folder/conections/query_string.html?hotelID=' + value.hotelId + '">' + value.name + '</a><br><img src="img/star.gif"  alt="" width="72" height="15"/></h4><p>'+ value.address1 + ' ' + value.city + ', ' + value.stateProvinceCode + ' ' + value.postalCode  +'</p><div class="row"><div class="span2"><p class="trip-advisor-rating">TripAdvisor Traveller Rating<br><img src="' + value.tripAdvisorRatingUrl + '"/></p></div><div class="span2"><img src="img/listing/map.jpg" alt=""/><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-sm btnMap">View map</button></div></div></div><div class="span2 pull-right p-block"><span class="rate-from">rate from</span><br /><div class="main-rate"><span class="main-currency">AU $</span>'+StrlowRate+'<br /><br /><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Book online</a></div></div></div></div><!-- /Listings -->');

            $('.btnMap').click(function(){
                $('.modal-title').text(value.name);
            });
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        //alert('no');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the `click` function out of your ajax call and add a `data-modaltitle` attribute to your `btnMap`, otherwise the `$('.modal-title').text(value.name);` will always have the last value from your `.each` iteration:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&city=Sydney&stateProvinceCode=QL&countryCode=AU&&numberOfResults=10&_type=json",
    results:{'pageSize':25},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;
        $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {
            var StrlowRate = parseInt(value.lowRate);
            $('.span9').append('<div class="listings"><div class="row"><div class="span2"><a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"><img src="http://images.travelnow.com' + value.thumbNailUrl + '" height="110" width="110"' + 'alt="' + value.name + '"/></a></div><div class="span5" style="margin-left:-20px;"><h4 class="media-heading"><a href="' +'../steven_folder/conections/query_string.html?hotelID=' + value.hotelId + '">' + value.name + '</a><br><img src="img/star.gif"  alt="" width="72" height="15"/></h4><p>'+ value.address1 + ' ' + value.city + ', ' + value.stateProvinceCode + ' ' + value.postalCode  +'</p><div class="row"><div class="span2"><p class="trip-advisor-rating">TripAdvisor Traveller Rating<br><img src="' + value.tripAdvisorRatingUrl + '"/></p></div><div class="span2"><img src="img/listing/map.jpg" alt=""/><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-modaltitle="' + value.name + '" class="btn btn-sm btnMap">View map</button></div></div></div><div class="span2 pull-right p-block"><span class="rate-from">rate from</span><br /><div class="main-rate"><span class="main-currency">AU $</span>'+StrlowRate+'<br /><br /><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Book online</a></div></div></div></div><!-- /Listings -->');
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        //alert('no');
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btnMap').on( 'click', function(e){
        var modaltitle = $(this).data('modaltitle');
        $('.modal-title').text(modaltitle);
    }); 
});
```